# .innerHTML is not defined

Tags: java, jquery, html, asp.net, dom

I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="main-nav" id="main-content">
        <ul class="main-nav-c">
            <li id="Li1"><a id="A1" disabled="disabled" class="sprites"><span
                class="headerV">Value 1</span></a></li>
            <li id="Li2"><a id="A2" class="sprites" >
                <span class="empx9b12">Value 2</span></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

and to get the innerHtml of the first li I use the following jquery

```
   value = $('#main-content .main-nav-c li').eq(0).find('a').find('.headerV')[0].innerHTML.trim().toUpperCase();
```

but I got the following error: $(...).eq(..).find(..).find(..)[0].innerHTML is undefined

Comment: try html() instead. https://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Log your object to see what it is (and that it's defined)

Comment: @walarawashdeh this works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pR7f5/, do you have jQuery library loaded.

Comment: @Jai this is strange I have all the needed libraries loaded.

Comment: @walarawashdeh check if jQuery libraries path is correct.

Answer (score 8):

You should have [logged your object](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console) to see what happens (you can for example do `console.log(myJqueryObject.length)`).

The problem here is that your selector is wrong : `main-nav` is a class not an id.

You probably wanted

```
$('#main-content .main-nav-c li')
```

Comment: No the UL has a class =main-nav-c

Comment: @walarawashdeh Well, the problem was the `#main-nav`.

Comment: ok I have edited it Now as in my original page but I still have the same problem

Comment: You should make a fiddle, then.

Answer (score 1):

```
value = $('.main-nav .main-nav-c li').find('a').find('.headerV').html().trim().toUpperCase();

console.log(value);
```

You made small mistake - by using # (id selector), rather than . class selector.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5MXWm/

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem by altering the jquery to

```
value = $('#main-content .main-nav-c li').eq(0).find('a').text().trim().toUpperCase();
```